# Are newer i5 CPUs quicker than an older i7s?

Tags: memory, ssd, cpu, macbook

- **2012 Macbook Pro:** i7-3520M 2.9GHz.
- **2013 Macbook Air:** i5-4250U 1.3 GHz.

Both 8gb RAM, both 13″ screens.

How does one calculate the difference in performance between the i5 and the i7 different-generation processors? Currently the Air seems to process even simple applications quicker than the Pro; could upgrading the Pro's (i7) HDD to an SSD produce processing times comparable to the Air's (i5) SSD?

Comment: http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-3520M-vs-Intel-Core-i5-4250U    and another one  http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-3520M-vs-Intel-Core-i5-4250U/m50vsm1787 As about SSD, no doubt it much faster that HDD and if your computer supports SSD NVMe than it is many times faster than regular SATA SSD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A single core of the [i7-3520M](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i7-3520M%20%40%202.90GHz&id=890) is objectively 22% faster than a single core of the [i5-4250U](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel%20Core%20i5-4250U%20%40%201.30GHz&id=1944) but when taking all 2 cores/4 threads into consideration then at 100% CPU usage the i7 is 31% faster.

The i7 will run hotter than the i5 because their TDPs are [35 W](https://ark.intel.com/products/64893/Intel-Core-i7-3520M-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) and [15 W](https://ark.intel.com/products/75028/Intel-Core-i5-4250U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_60-GHz) which is probably why the i7's base clock is 2.9 GHz but the i5's is only 1.3 GHz

The reason that opening apps on the i5 is faster than the i7 is due to the SSD. Opening an app is heavily bound by the speed of the storage solution.

However, once you get an app open such as Photoshop then image manipulation will be noticeably faster using the i7 because its performance is no longer bounded by the HDD. This same principle applies for other apps as well; as long as the app is not constantly using the HDD/SSD then you are bound by the speed of the CPU, the amount of RAM, and to a much lesser extent the speed of RAM.

If you get an SSD for the i7 then it will win all speed comparisons.

Comment: And the same if they are both dual-core? Because currently the i5 opens applications, for example, quicker than the i7..

Comment: That's because the i5 has an SSD so access times are much lower. If you were doing work in Photoshop then the i7 would be faster even with the HDD since images are manipulated in memory so the cpu is unbound by storage constraints. Add an ssd to the i7 and the i5 will be slower for all tests.

Comment: @Jacob Not sure if you saw my comment, I wasn't able to tag you because I was on my phone. Check out my updated answer though.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted this but it would be helpful to know which part of my assessment is incorrect.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I did not downvote but the i5 has a better (in some uses) integrated graphics, so your comparison with Photoshop would again depend how exactly it is used.

Comment: @NordlysJeger both IGPs are quite terrible and I don't think there would be an appreciable difference when using one over the other to be honest so I chose to leave out that comparison since most tasks are CPU bound.

Comment: That's true, altough the i5 has a lot more shader cores (more than double IIRC). Neverthe less are IGP's almost always undersized when it comes to tasks like Photoshop.

Comment: @NordlysJeger Absolutely. A better bang for your buck for the IGP is finding out whether or not the laptop utilizes dual-channel or single channel in the RAM configuration. Those benchmarks have consistently shown almost double performance when dual-channel is used. By simply having 2x4GB instead of 1x8GB you can gain performance or if the MBP has 1x8GB then buy another compatible 8GB for free performance.